# Twitter search : avoid keyword matching replied username

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

The body of a tweet reply is having a list of `@username` at the beginning.
When you search for a `keyword`, it can match a username in this list.

For example, searching `keyword` will match:

*Tweet A :*

> This is an exemple tweet speaking about keyword

*Tweet B : (a reply tweet)*

> @keyword Speaking about random topic

There is multiple solution to exclude tweet replies using `-filter:replies` or `exclude:replies`, but it will remove all replies. It won't be possible to match tweet like :
*Tweet C :*

> @username Reply speaking about keyword

Is it possible to search a keyword only within tweet content, without matching to a name in front of a reply tweet ? Having a query to match only Tweet A and C.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[keyword] -from:[keyword] -@[keyword] -to:[keyword]
```

Where `[keyword]` is, of course, any keyword you choose.

- `-from:[keyword]` will exclude tweets from the `@keyword` user
- `-@[keyword]` will exclude tweets mentioning the user `@keyword`
- `-to:[keyword]` will exclude tweets replying to the user `@keyword`